# Replace all numbers in a df by median

Tags: r, replace, na

I would like to replace all numbers in my `df` by the median of the row, maintaining the NA values. This is my input:

```
df <- 'pr_id  sample1  sample2 sample3 median
            AX-1   NA       120     130  125    
            AX-2   NA       NA     NA  NA
            AX-3   NA       NA     196  196'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

This is my expected output:

```
df <- 'pr_id  sample1  sample2 sample3
            AX-1   NA       125     125    
            AX-2   NA       NA     NA
            AX-3   NA       NA     196'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

Some idea to accomplish that?

Comment: You already calculated the row medians?

Comment: Yes it is in the last column. May I change the questions title to "Replace all numbers in a df by the last collumn"?

Comment: I would leave the title as it is, it is more fun to calculate median on the fly.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Because it was incomplete. This is funnier: `df[,2:4]-df[,2:4]+(!is.na(df[,2:4]))*df$median`

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not. At least not intentionally... I am also looking for that

Comment: @nicola nice golfing there. I've tried my luck with a less golfed option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible base solution

```
indx <- which(!is.na(df[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE) # find non-NA incidents
df[-1][indx] <- df$median[indx[, "row"]] # replace them while subsetting accordingly from df$median
df
#   pr_id sample1 sample2 sample3 median
# 1  AX-1      NA     125     125    125
# 2  AX-2      NA      NA      NA     NA
# 3  AX-3      NA      NA     196    196
```

---

And a bonus, if you don't have the medians yet, here's a possible way to calcualte them on the fly

```
df[-1][indx] <- matrixStats::rowMedians(as.matrix(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)[indx[, "row"]]
```

Answer (score 6):

With pure math:

```
cbind(df[1],NA^(is.na(df[,2:4]))*df$median)  

#  pr_id sample1 sample2 sample3
#1  AX-1      NA     125     125
#2  AX-2      NA      NA      NA
#3  AX-3      NA      NA     196
```

If you need to calculate the median, just replace `df$median` with `apply(df[,2:4],1,median,na.rm=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 5):

Using dplyr you can do as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_each(df, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), ., median)), sample1:sample3)
#  pr_id sample1 sample2 sample3 median
#1  AX-1      NA     125     125    125
#2  AX-2      NA      NA      NA     NA
#3  AX-3      NA      NA     196    196
```

---

If you want to include the median calculation, one option is to convert to long format, compute medians and re-convert to wide format:

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, sample, value, sample1:sample3) %>% 
  group_by(pr_id) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(value), value, median(value, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>% 
  spread(sample, value)
```